# Exclude current object from has_many belongs_to query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A shoe has_many socks. Socks belong to shoes.

Using the socks controller I want to make a comparison to siblings with the same parent_id as shoe.

```
SocksController
  def show
    @sock = Sock.find(params[:id])
    @shoe = Shoe.find(@sock.shoe_id)
    @socks = @shoe.socks
  end
```

socks - show.html.erb

```
  <% @socks.each do |sock| %>
    <%= link_to sock.sock_name %>
  <% end %>
```

Naturally I'm getting all the socks in show.html.erb, but I want to exclude my current sock from @socks = @shoe.socks. Is there a way to do this? I'm exploring where.not options now, but have never tried this before.

Additionally is there inherently anything wrong with my initial def show? I think it's ok, but feel like I'm being redundant in my calls, and that I might be able to simplify it to reduce queries.

Comment: You could filter it out with `@socks = @shoe.socks.where.not(id: params[:id])`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'll do a comparison of the methods and see which is faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to exclude your current sock in the view, you could do something like this.

```
    <% @socks.each do |sock| %>
      <% next if sock.id == @sock.id %>
      <%= link_to sock.sock_name %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: That's just what I was looking for. Thanks for sharing next if with me.